# Why does my finger not conduct electricity when I press on my laptop case?

Tags: electricity, charge, electrical-resistance

I have an aluminium laptop and when it is plugged in and I brush over the case I feel a small tickeling when brushing **lightly** on the case. I have read that is coming from grounding issues and this feeling is a current that is running through my fingertips.

My question is, why does this sensation not happen when I touch the case with fingers from both hands and why does it also not happen if I press on the case?

Answer (score 0):

> this feeling is a current that is running through my fingertips

I don't think so, I think you're feeling the effects of a small net charge on the surface.

When you run your fingers lightly there some small separation between the charges in your finger and the surface and you're feeling the exchange.

But if you press harder the slight charge on the surface is wiped out through sheer mass. Even if you move your fingers in this case, there's so much contact patch that it just overwhelms the slight exchange.

Just a guess though.